# is it possible to use inline css in a drupal 6 header block to get a repeating background image?

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-6

I've found some info on how to create a repeating background header image in general, but I am trying to do this within a drupal 6 block. Basically I have a banner image and I want to extend the edges so that they repeat all the way across the screen. 
 I don't have access to any of the server files so I can't work with the css there. Is it possible to just create a class within the body of the block? I know it's not the best practice- but is it possible? I'm working on this with someone who has been swamped in other higher priority work so I'm getting desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put any css in `<style>` tags within the body of the document (and specifically in this case in the body of a block).

This is not best practice but you already know that.